# Mount a rackspace drive in linux

Tags: backup, rackspace-cloud

Is there any software that will allow me to mount a rackspace drive in linux? I want to copy sql files from my database onto my rackspace. I have web min running a backup nightly and copying those backups offsite would be ideal for obvious reasons.

On my windows desktop I've been using cyber duck to upload/download and manage files on the server.

I purchased a subscription to "Jungle Disk" but this problem was unstable on all the systems I had available in my office - ubuntu and win 7. The application itself seems alright but any click took on average 10 seconds to respond.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to the most simple way to copy this stuff to rackspace??

I have a  cloud-files account and am using ubuntu.

Thanks

Jason

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/176199/how-can-i-mount-a-rackspace-cloud-files-as-a-drive-on-a-mac-pc

Comment: @mailq I need a linux solution, not a "Mac & PC" solution.

Comment: All answers to that "Mac" question tell you how it works for "Linux".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I work for Rackspace, and I can help.

Take a look at Cloudfuse (https://github.com/redbo/cloudfuse). It enables you to mount your Cloud Files container as a volume for storage and retrieval of static content.

There's a good tutorial at http://sandeepsidhu.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/mounting-cloud-files-using-cloudfuse-into-ubuntu-10-10-v2/.

It's important to note that it would be inappropriate and inadvisable to attempt to install an application or database on the remote Cloud Files volume, as it was not designed for that.

For best results, configure your database backup to dump the database to a file on the local filesystem first, then copy the dump to the appropriate Cloud Files container.

If you need any other help, feel free to contact me, or contact our support team by phone, live chat, or ticket (http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/aboutus/contact/).

Comment: Looks like all these posts are outdated! Do they still work?